# Is asking about players interviews (which is not related to chess board) allowed and constructive?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I flagged this question as off-topic and it's declined.

[*"What was the question asked to Magnus Carlsen which he refused to translate?"*](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4067/1824)

Someone tell me, is it really an exact chess problem? Maybe we need a stack-exchange site like: interview.stackexchange.com! for these type of questions.